# How to turn this Flow chart into "workable" code in C?

Tags: c

Let me begin by saying I have no idea what I'm doing with code. The most I can do is make an LED blink on an Arduino... And even then, I'm a cheater by uploading the pre-installed sketch and edit variables to make the light blink faster or slower... Nothing more. I've done multiple searches to find something understandable and coherent (in my mind being a non coder) but I can't find anything that matches my needs.

With the above said, I have included a flow chart that details how I want my code to work AS IF it were real code to make something work... For example, when an input is sensed (the diamonds), the code prints words (output). How would I write this code in C? (sorry for horrible tagging, I couldn't figure out anything that would pop up other than the one you see).

The purpose of this is to write the code on paper for a cute love note to my wife.

[image]

Comment: You cannot turn this into real code since the means of "input", such as _smile detection_ is not defined - unless the intent is you prompt the user for input _"Is she smiling?"_ for example.  This could only ever be pseudo-code - even if "C-like". You should perhaps make a start, then we will have a better idea of what you are trying to do.  BTW SO has its own image hosting - using DropBox is inappropriate.

Comment: @Clifford, think of the input as if it were a button or facial recognition or something. The idea is just to be cute. Basically, I just need code written that has an input variable which results in an output variable. For example, when a button is pushed, an LED lights up. If the LED is NOT pushed, the light does nothing. The "do nothing" part is just part of the flow chart that indicates if there is no input, then there is no output. My wife is a coder, and she would understand what I was trying to do with the code, jut it kinda ruins the surprise of a cute love note, if I have her code it.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica well, firstly, I would have to know my wife and how she reacts to the cute sentimental things I do for her... For example, when she gets the letter, she's already going to be smiling. Now, like I told Clifford, the code just needs to be in the format of "when a button is pressed, do this action" in reference to the multiple statements... It's just an if/or statement... So IF she smiles OR she has tears of joy, then the output is hugs and kisses. I think you're looking into this too critically. All I need is a code that would work if there's and input and an output

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica from there, I would fill in the "inputs and outputs" with my own cute variables. But to make a proper realistic functioning code as if using buttons and leds, I don't know how to do.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica that's why I grouped them into the same box? None the less, every thing you just said is alien to me. Kinda like the language C (or any other coding language for that matter). That's why I'm asking for help in the matter. As I told Mike, I agree about the flow chart, but it lacks the "nerdy me" side that my wife loves. Any Joe schmo can make a flow chart... But to have code written is more meaningful, especially to her.

Comment: @Clifford I forgot to address the Dropbox comment... The reason I linked it to Dropbox, is because I couldn't get the file to upload in the app nor on the website on my phone It kept giving me an error, and I didn't want to have a question on Stack that lacked the proper image for people to see what my goal was (I also don't have access to internet for my laptop). Thus, I just linked a copy of it to my Dropbox as a last ditch effort... Gotta do what ya gotta do sometimes.

Comment: Are you really stuck just trying to get some reasonable working approximation in C of the flowchart logic? If you are let me know and I'm happy to add a serious answer using a random value for open/closed, smiling and tears of joy so that the output logic and be demonstrated. What I would do is just use the `rand()` function to generate a random integer and then test odd/even for each of the conditions and then create the conditions of `if (open) { ... if (smiling) { ... if (tearsofjoy) { ... }}}` or something very similar. Let me know.

Comment: @PiGuy88 : the issue with your image was that it exceeded the 2Mb limit.  I cropped it slightly.

Answer (score 3):

> The purpose of this is to write the code on paper for a cute love note to my wife.

I think you have done this already. Your flowchart is much more charming than any C code could ever be.

My only worry is the "do nothing" boxes. You might want to seek feedback on that from your end user, and revise the logic as needed.

This will help teach you the art of debugging, a skill you will need for every programming language you ever use.

In fact I suggest working through the entire chart with her. You never know what might happen!

And you won't need a single line of C code to do it.

One more thing... Keep the old versions of the chart if you revise it. This way you will learn about version control, and you will have a fun story to share with your grandchildren.

Comment: version control :D

Comment: The output is triggered. I also feel that sending her a flow chart is just too basic, regardless of how cute it is.

Comment: @PiGuy88 It seems to me that you want to render this flowchart into something that looks like code for purposes other than actual coding.  In that sense it is probably off-topic in SO.  I wonder who will have the heart of stone to close the question?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll play this silly game and make like some nerdy Cyrano de Bergerac!

Your flow chart does not really work - you have some "do nothing forever" dead ends - which seems rather tragic! I have interpreted this to mean rather "do nothing until..." which would look like:

[image]

which may be visually less attractive, but at least does not speak of the death of your marriage!

That being the case then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <letter.h>
#include <wife.h>
#include <love.h>

int main()
{
    while( !letterOpen() ) { }

    printf( "Dear honey,\n\n" ) ;
    while( !wifeSmiling( ANY ) ){ }

    printf( "I just wanted to say\n" ) ;
    while( !wifeSmiling( TEARS_OF_JOY ) ){ }

    printf( "I love you\n" ) ;
    while( !wifeSmiling( TEARS_OF_JOY ) ){ }

    printf( "\nLove your loving husband\n" ) ;
    while( !wifeSmiling( TEARS_OF_JOY ) ){ }

    doHugs() ;
    doKisses() ;

    return SUCCESS ;
}
```

Output:

```
Dear honey,

I just wanted to say
I love you

Love your loving husband
```